# Laravel get date at the select query from the Datetime field

Tags: mysql, laravel

Can anyone explain how get the date from the datetime in the Laravel raw query.

I want to convert select array Datetime field to Date. How would I do it in a query? So far I tried:

```
SELECT(array('taxi.taxi_no AS plateNumber', 'taxi_driver_mapping.mapping_startdate AS joinedDate' ));
```

Comment: show the code what you have tried so far

Comment: select(array('taxi.taxi_no as plateNumber',
                    'taxi_driver_mapping.mapping_startdate as joinedDate'
                ));

Comment: Adding the code from comment and editing the post

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DB::raw()` for get date from DateTime for example

```
$tableName = tableName::select(['taxi.taxi_no as plateNumber',DB::raw('DATE(`taxi_driver_mapping.mapping_startdate`)  as joinedDate')])->get();
```

Comment: select(array('taxi.taxi_no as plateNumber', 'taxi_driver_mapping.mapping_startdate as joinedDate' ));  I use as an array